# Hapi.js Catbox Redis returning "server.cache is not a function"

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, hapi.js

So I'm like 99% sure I'm just screwing up something dumb here.

I'm trying to set up catbox to cache objects to redis. I have redis up and running and I can hit it with RDM (sql pro like utility for redis) but Hapi is not cooperating.

I register the redis catbox cache like so:

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({
cache: [
{
  name: 'redisCache',
  engine: require('catbox-redis'),
  host: 'redis',
  partition: 'cache',
  password: 'devpassword'
}
]
});
```

I am doing this in server.js After this block of code I go on to register some more plugins and start the server. I also export the server at the end of the file

```
module.exports = server;
```

Then in my routes file, I am attempting to set up a testing route like so:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/cacheSet/{key}/{value}',
    config: { auth: false },
    handler: function(req, res) {
        const testCache = server.cache({
            cache: 'redisCache',
            expireIn: 1000
        });

        testCache.set(req.params.key, req.params.value, 1000, function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            res(Boom.create(e.http_code, e.message));
         })
        res(req.params.key + " " + req.params.value);
    }
},
```

**Note:** My routes are in an external file, and are imported into server.js where I register them.

If I comment out all the cache stuff on this route, the route runs fine and returns my params.

If I run this with the cache stuff, at first I got "server not defined". So I then added

```
const server                        = require('./../server.js');
```

to import the server.

Now when I run this, I get "server.cache is not a function" and a 500 error.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. My guess is that I'm importing server, but perhaps it's the object without all the configs set so it's unable to use the .cache method. However this seems wrong because .cache should always be a default method with the default memory cache, so even if my cache registration isn't active yet, server.cache should theoretically still be a method.

I know it has to be something basic I'm messing up, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was correct. I was doing something stupid. It had to do with how I was exporting my server. I modified my structure to pull out the initial server creation and make it more modular. Now I am simply exporting JUST the server like so:

```
'use strict';
const Hapi       = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server({
  cache: [
    {
      name: 'redisCache',
      engine: require('catbox-redis'),
      host: 'redis',
      partition: 'cache',
      password: 'devpassword'
    }
  ]
});
module.exports = server;
```

I then import that into my main server file (now index.js previously server.js) and everything runs fine. I can also import this into any other file (in this case my routes file) and access the server for appropriate methods.

Redis is happily storing keys and Hapi is happily not giving me errors.

Leaving here in case anyone else runs into a dumb mistake like this.

Comment: Hi trattles, I am using catbox-redis for caching purpose and i am getting issue on it. It doesn't set the value, rather it displaying disconnected eror. If you anything about it please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779511/catbox-redis-is-showing-disconnected-error-on-my-hapijs-application

Comment: you can also get the server inside handler by using request.server